# How I output the total sum in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Let's say I want to know the total sum of a list which goes from 0 to 100 which is 5050? I loop through my list:

```
c=0
for i in range(0,101):
   c+=i
   print(c)
```

The problem is I want just the last element not all of them.

Comment: add some sample code here

Comment: Just print `c` after the loop then, if you do not want to see intermediate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the Print Indentation.

Try the below Code,

```
c=0
for i in range(0,101):
   c+=i
print(c)
```

Comment: `c=+i` should be `c+=i`

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the value of variable "c" in the loop. To print only the sum, remove the indentation of "print(c)". And you are doing "=+" but you should do "+=" to obtain the sum.

```
c=0
for i in range(0,101):
   c+=i 
print(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a python function just for this - [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

```py
print(sum([x for x in range(1, 101)]))
```

Edit: To address the concern about "struggling to understand"

`[x for x in range(1, 101)]` is called a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python/). They are used to create lists in a singular line, without using `for` loops - python can be a functional programming language after all. `[x for x in range(1, 101)]` returns a list from 1 to 100, that is-

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ......., 99, 100]
```

We skip 0 because it doesn't count in the sum anyway.

Now if you do `sum()` on this list, it'll return the sum of *all elements in the list*.

Hence `sum([for x in range (1, 101)])` returns the sum of all numbers from 1 to 100 (inclusive) and `print` will print the final result.

Why use many lines when few do trick? :)

Remember, List Comprehension and `sum()` are 2 very important tools in the python toolbox, everyone should know about these 2.

Comment: newbie will struggle to undestand this @Chase

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you provided here, you missed the indentation of the print statement, if you keep it this way

```
c=0
for i in range(0,101):
   c+=i
   print(c)
```

It will print all the sum because it is inside for loop as per the current indentation, but if you want only the final output, change the indentation of the print statement like below

```
c=0
for i in range(0,101):
   c+=i
print(c)
```

Now it is not inside for loop, it will only print final value of the sum(c).